# Iterate and get values from a simple angular dictionary

Tags: angular, dictionary

This is my code:

`nationalityDictionary = {
    'AF': 'Afghanistan',
    'AX': 'Åland Islands',
    'AL': 'Albania',
    'DZ': 'Algeria',
    'AS': 'American Samoa',
    'AD': 'Andorra',
    'AO': 'Angola',
    ...
    'EH': 'Western Sahara',
    'YE': 'Yemen',
    'ZM': 'Zambia',
    'ZW': 'Zimbabwe'
  };`

I would like to get out of it an array or country codes: 
`wantedResoult = {"AF","AX","AL","DZ","AS","AD","AO",...,"EH","YE", ,"ZM","ZW"}`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `Object.keys(nationalityDictionary)` will give an array of what you want. `{'AF', 'AX'...}` is an invalid format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Oject.keys` to get the keys

```
let wantedResoult =Object.keys(nationalityDictionary)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var nationalityDictionary = {
        'AF': 'Afghanistan',
        'AX': 'Åland Islands',
        'AL': 'Albania',
        'DZ': 'Algeria',
        'AS': 'American Samoa',
        'AD': 'Andorra',
        'AO': 'Angola',
        'EH': 'Western Sahara',
        'YE': 'Yemen',
        'ZM': 'Zambia',
        'ZW': 'Zimbabwe'
      };
      var countriesKeys = Object.keys(nationalityDictionary).map(function(key) {
        return key;
      });
      console.log(countriesKeys);
```